# CSS nested class can't be selected directly?

Tags: html, css

I have to style an image with the class `offer-img`

```html
<section class="offer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <!-- The image I want to style -->
        <img src="img.png" class="offer-img">
      </div>

      <div class=".."> ... </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In my style.css, when I try to access it with

```css
/* somewhere above the hierarchy */
.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-size: cover;
}
/* Not working  
.offer-img {
  padding: 40px;
}
*/

/* Works fine */
.col-2 .offer-img {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

**Edited:**

- When I try to access the `.offer-img` directly, my style is not applied.
- It only works when I change `.offer-img` to  `.col-2 .offer-img`
- Why `.col-2 img`'s padding is overriding `.offer-img`'s padding?
- Is  `.col-2 img` more specific than `.offer-img`

Comment: Probably the first rule is being overridden. You can check this in the dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can access the class directly and there is nothing wrong with your code.

You are seeing [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in action here

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.

The three css classes you used:

1. `.offer-img`: an element with the class *.offer-img* *(less specific)*
2. `.col-2 img`: img element inside an element with class-name *.col2* *(more specific)*
3. `.col-2 .offer-img`: an element with class-name *.offer-img* inside an element with class-name *.col2* *(most specific)*

The most specific style for the element will be applied if there are conflicts.

Comment: Specificity of ```.col-2 img``` > ```.offer-img``` That's why this happens right?

Answer (score 2):

there's a typo here you've missed closing Quotation mark `class="row>` it should be `class="row">` besides code is working just fine, i could select the class you're referring to without any issues & see if you're overriding styles.

```css
.offer-img{
    padding: 50px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="offer">
      <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-2">  
                       <!-- The image I want to style --> 
                       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/193101.jpg
" class="offer-img">
                    </div>

                   <div class=".."> ...  </div>
              </div>
       </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. ```.col-2 img { padding: 50px 0; }``` is overriding the padding. But why ```.img-offer``` class hasn't taken precendence?

Comment: If you write 2 classes one after the other same way without giving any importance, last written class will override the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Check If there is any css for only "img" tag in your style sheet which override your this class

Else give "!important" like

```
.offer-img {
  padding: 40px !important;
}
```

The '!important' rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal